# reply_markup in telegram bots (node js)

Tags: node.js, api, telegram

I'm trying to write a telegram bot using node js, and I'm sending a keyboard to a user:

```
var keyboards = {  
    main_menu: {
        reply_markup: {
            keyboard: [
                [{text: "Cards"}, {text: "Progress"}],
                [{text: "Warning"}, {text: "Help"}]
            ]
        }
    }
};
bot.onText(/\/keyboard/, (msg) => {
    console.log(keyboards.main_menu);
    bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, "Main menu", keyboards.main_menu);
    console.log(keyboards.main_menu);
});
```

And that's what I have on console:

```
{ reply_markup: { keyboard: [ [Array], [Array] ] } }
{ reply_markup:
   '{"keyboard":[[{"text":"Cards"},{"text":"Progress"}],[{"text":"Warning"}, {"text":"Help"}]]}',
  chat_id: 276984822,
  text: 'Main menu' }
```

So I don't know why, but after sending a keyboard Telegram adds `chat_id` and `text` to my keyboard. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to solve it - you should send keyboards like this:

`bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, "Main menu", {reply_markup: keyboards.main_menu});`

And actually next variant also gonna work:

`bot.sendMessage(msg.from.id, "Main menu", {reply_markup: keyboards.main_menu.reply_keyboard});`